# Management of the records inside of a store in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am working in a new feature of my sencha app, I have a button (it is possible to have more than one button) and this button fires a modal window with the possibilty to add records to the store, and It works correctly, problem comes when I have more than one button, my records appears repeated, cloning the same records, but the records should be independently for each modal window "inside" of the button...

Here the code used in the controller to manage the tap event on the button..

```
    Ext.getStore('SetItemConditions').on({
        'removerecords': this.onSetItemConditionChange,
        'addrecords': this.onSetItemConditionChange,
        'updaterecord': this.onSetItemConditionChange,
        'clear': this.onSetItemConditionChange,
        scope: this
    });

manageSetItemConditions: function (button) {
    var conditionsStore = Ext.getStore('SetItemConditions'),
        orderTypeConditionsStore = this.getCartHeader().down('#headerOrderType').getRecord().sconditions(),
        view = Ext.create('Cicero.view.cart.Conditions', {
            orderTypeConditionsStore: orderTypeConditionsStore
        });
    //view.setRecordId(record.getId());
    view.down('dataview').setStore(conditionsStore);
    view.showBy(button);
},
```

I hope to explain me correctly and sorry for my english

Comment: Can you perhaps demonstrate a minimum-use-case on senchafiddle ? We need to see more code.

Comment: I have edited the post with more code.. it is difficult to move this code to the fiddle.. but my workflow is:  firstly I have this code in the controller, and  I have created a store normally.. I am looking with the sencha-touch inspector extension records are saved... but for each button I need to refresh the records because they have independent values..

Comment: Where exactly do you add a clone record to the store? I would expect something like `store.add(record.copy());` in your code.

Comment: I dont need copies of records, I need different records, added dinamically, in different modal windows.. in a shared store..  :-|

Comment: Not sure that I understand the use case but If you want to use a shared store for multiple modal window views then you will need to apply a filter to the store for each window.

Comment: Example would be very useful..